# Topologically interesting non-abelian instantons

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, yang-mills, instantons

Consider a Yang-Mills type theory, with algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, defined over a manifold $M$. The action functional$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$ is
$$S[a] = \frac{1}{2g^2}\int_M\tr_\mathfrak{g}(f\wedge\star f),$$
where $f$ is the curvature of the connection $a$. You can add a $\theta$ term but it won't play a role. My question is *what are the instantons over $M$ of arbitrary topology*?

In the abelian case, $\mathfrak{g}=\mathbb{R}$, i.e. in the case of Maxwell theory, instantons exist only when $M$ has non-trivial topology (cf. [this phys.SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/731769/142398)). This is easy to see as the only solutions to Maxwell equations with finite, non-zero, action are harmonic 2-forms. This is all. Cool.

In the non-abelian case, I have only seen instantons on $M=\mathbb{R}^4$ (or at most, topologically trivial manifolds). They are given by the [ADHM construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADHM_construction). But this isn't all there is to it, right?

More explicitly, let's see what happens over a fixed background flat connection, $A\in\Omega^1(M;\mathfrak{g})$. In this case $f_A$ is an element of $\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{d}_A)$, where $\mathrm{d}_A = \mathrm{d}+A\wedge\phantom{a}$. $\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{d}_A)$ has a Hodge decomposition similar to $\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{d})$, as
$$ \mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{d}_A)\cong \mathrm{H}^2(M;\mathfrak{g}|\mathrm{d}_A)\oplus \mathrm{d}_A \Omega^1(M;\mathfrak{g}),$$
where $\mathrm{H}^2(M;\mathfrak{g}|\mathrm{d}_A)$, is the cohomology with respect to $\mathrm{d}_A$. So one would write
$$f_A = f_A^0 + \mathrm{d}_A a = f_A^0 + \mathrm{d}a+\frac{1}{2}[A\wedge a],$$
with $f_A^0 \in \mathrm{H}^2(M;\mathfrak{g}|\mathrm{d}_A)$.

Promoting the background connection to a dynamical one, the ADHM construction is concerned with $f = \mathrm{d}_a a\in\mathrm{d}_a\Omega^1(M;\mathfrak{g})$. $f$ can globally take this form if $M$ is such that $\mathrm{H}^2(M;\mathfrak{g}|\mathrm{d}_a)$ is trivial for all connections $a$, selecting thus, flat space. In other words, the ADHM construction, deals with topologically trivial instantons. What is known about topologically non-trivial instantons? I.e. those coming from $\mathrm{H}^2(M;\mathfrak{g}|\mathrm{d}_a)$?

As a concrete question, where the algebra and the manifold are tame enough and we know quite a lot about both, *do we know, say, all the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ instantons on the four-torus?*

Comment: I do not know much but for those instantons the moduli space is not simply connected. It was schown that on $S^3 \times S^1$, $SU(N)$-instantons can be interpreted as a collection of $N$ monpoles. Other than that I believe there is not much known besides the fact that on $Y \times \mathbb{R}$, where $Y$ is a homology three-sphere, instantons are integral flow-lines of the gradient flow of the Chern-Simons action functional. That is they decay exponentially. See for example :Donaldson,Floer homology groups in Yang-Mills theory.

Comment: If one consideres topological Yang-Mills, than the BRST quantization yields a $N=2$ super YM-theory in four dimensions, which is topologically twisted. This theory was first considered by Witten in "Topological field theory". Its partition function computes the Donaldson polynomials. It is also called cohomological Yang-Mills theory.  There is basicly an infinite rank vector bundle over the instanon moduli space. Essentially, the partition function computes the Mathai-Quillen representative of the Thom-class of this bundle. These are isomporhic to the equivariant Euler characteristic classes.

Comment: Later developments by Nekrasov and Seiberg and Witten led to the Nekrasov instanton partition functions. This is exatly the generating function of the equivariant Euler characteritic classes of the instanton moduli space. Famously by the AGT-duality it is dual to the conformal blocks of affine W-algebras. So while instantons are interesting, in physics, we are more interested in cohomolgies and representations.

Comment: As a last remark: Abelian instantons exist also on non-commutative $\mathbb{R}^4$.